# bitmap is not saving into an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

so it's basic.. I need this bitmap to save the red square image into an array... but it's showing me that I am accessing an unidentified method or property... this is more or less my first time with array's and I saw a bunch of tuts on hw to use them and for what and I think this is how they pointed to assign them to something..so please if I am doing something wrong can somebody tell me..I am just trying to learn how they work by trying them out...

```
var myImages:Array;

red_square.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, firstchoice);
function firstchoice (e:MouseEvent){
    finalsave.redsquare = 1;
    myImages[0] = new BitmapData(151, 167);
    bitmap = new Bitmap (myImages[0]);
    addChild(bitmap);
    myImages[0].draw (red_square);
    gotoAndPlay(5);
    stop();
};
```

the error I get is

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at gamefile_fla::MainTimeline/firstchoice()[gamefile_fla.MainTimeline::frame4:13]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array starts off empty, so when you try and access position zero it gets confused. Instead of using this line of code:
 `myImages[0] = new BitmapData(151, 167);`
 use
 `myImages.push(new BitmapData(151, 167));`
The push command will add an element to the end of an array, so the size will increase by 1. Now you are safe to use `myImages[0].draw(red_square);`.
Also when you declare your array variable, `var myImages:Array` it's good practice to initialize it, either in a constructor or some method, so change it to `var myImages:Array = new Array();`.

Comment: yh it still didn't fix it.. :(

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at gamefile_fla::MainTimeline/firstchoice()[gamefile_fla.MainTimeline::frame4:13]

Comment: post it to the comments or edit your original questions to include it.

Comment: it fit in here actually hehe :D

Comment: myImages.push(new BitmapData(151, 167));

Comment: Just out of curriousity did you import `flash.display.BitmapData`?

Comment: yep that's included already... also the bitmap one is included

Comment: also did you initiate the array by doing `myImages = new Array();` or `var myImages:Array = new Array();`?

Comment: oh no was I suppose to? I thought it would pick on it's own ;p let me give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Actually you haven't instantiated the array before accessing it. 
Try this:

```
var myImages:Array= new Array();
```